# Toad oracle 10.5

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

my issue is the compiling was working fine and then suddenly the
compile started taking too long time ...
and then after few mins i get
this error :

```
[Error] ORA-04021 (0: 0): ORA-04021: timeout occurred while waiting to lock object ..(procedure name )
```

Comment: Some other process has the object you are trying to compile.

Comment: check object is blocked session and kill them 
SELECT ORACLE_USERNAME, OS_USER_NAME,LOCKED_MODE,OBJECT_NAME,OBJECT_TYPE
    FROM V$LOCKED_OBJECT A, DBA_OBJECTS B
    WHERE A.OBJECT_ID=B.OBJECT_ID